# Programmatically setting field value for sharepoint listitem

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, spfield

I'm trying to simply add a simple text or hyperlink field to a list item in sharepoint 2007.

I can add the field no problem:

```
list.Fields.Add("MyField",SPFieldType.Text, false);
```

And it shows up fine on my list items.
However no matter which way I try, I can't programmatically set a value for the field. I tried:

```
list.items[0]["MyField"] = "text";
```

and I tried loading into a field:

```
SPField field = list.items[0].Fields["MyField"];
```

and setting it there, and setting the default value and updating, but nothing what so ever happens.

I always finish my code blocks with list.update(); or if I'm operating on the item itself item.update(); so I'm not at least missing that. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Are ContentTypes enabled in the list?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
SPListItem item = list.items[0];
item["MyField"] = "text";
item.Update();
```

Although it seems equivalent, the above code is not the same as:

```
list.items[0]["MyField"] = "text";
list.items[0].Update();
```

For more information, see [here](http://stevesps.blogspot.com/2007/04/splistitemupdate-isnt-updating.html) and [here](http://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2008/11/12/when-an-splistitem-wont-update-or-change-2/) for people who have documented the same behavior.

Comment: Why on earth would they mess up the indexers so bad? :/

Comment: @Dynde They don't. This is no different than if a value type was returned and modified. It's just that a *new* object is returned.

Answer (score 3):

Could you try this for adding a new field and setting a default value? Untested code. let me know how it goes.

```
SPFieldText fldName = (SPFieldText)list.Fields.CreateNewField(SPFieldType.Text.ToString(), "mycolumn");
fldName.DefaultValue = "default";
list.Fields.Add(fldName);
list.Update();
```

Answer (score 1):

I've always found the best route is to get a reference to the list item directly and update specifically, as opposed to using the indexer route. Just like rich's first example mentions.

http://www.sharepointdevwiki.com/display/public/Updating+a+List+Item+programmatically+using+the+object+model

Answer (score 0):

From all the discussion above it appears that you are trying to set the field value in a list event handler and you are setting the value in item adding or item updating event. If this is the case then you need to consider AfterProperties. Remember we have *ing and *ed events and in case of *ing events we need to work with BeforeProperties and AfterProperties.

I hope this helps!